# Using Nokogiri and Rails to parse page img, by width or height dimensions

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse img's on any particular web page, which is working fine except I only want to pass imgs with a width value or higher then.   For example, if a img has a width greater then 300px we should include the url to the image, if not, we shouldn't include it in the array.

```
    # sort all the images and make absolute url path & check for http

      product_url = "http://example.com/product.htm" 

      Nokogiri::HTML(open(product_url)).xpath("//img/@src").each do |src|
      uri = make_absolute(src,product_url)
      @all_image_urls << uri
    end
```

I've attempted something like this with no luck

```
    # sort all the images and make absolute url path & check for http

      product_url = "http://example.com/product.htm" 

      Nokogiri::HTML(open(product_url)).xpath("//img[:width > 100]/@src").each do |src|
      uri = make_absolute(src,product_url)
      @all_image_urls << uri
    end
```

the issue i'm running into is the actual filtering on the image size.  Since this might not even be available at the HTML level, how could we go about this? Can we get the dimension of the image like this and then filter?

I've currently trying to solve this server side, before it hits the view/presentation logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(product_url))
 @all_image_urls = doc.css('img').select{|img| img[:src] if img[:width].to_i > 100}
```